# How to check if the value after URL is set

Tags: php

I just wonder how to check if the value after URL is set.
Etc:

```
http://example.com/821302
```

I don't need to know how to get the value, I just wanna know how to check if it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

**So for example:**

```
if(parse_url('http://example.com/821302', PHP_URL_PATH)){
    echo 'has path';
}else{
    echo 'has no path';
}
```